# hiding the action bar throws an error when the smartphone is rotated

Tags: android, rotation

I have the following code to detect when the smartphone is rotated and hide the actionbar:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        getActionBar().hide();
    }
    else {
        getActionBar().hide();
    }
}
```

The app throws a null pointer exeption:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
```

when the smartphone is rotated

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is redundant. `getActionBar().hide() is always called, regardless of the new configuration being portrait or landscape.` Also,
it would appear you need a null check there

```
if(getActionBar() != null)
       getActionBar().hide()
```

I don't know what are you trying to do, but this doesn't seem the right way. Why not do this instead, in `onCreate`:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)

...

getActionBar().hide()
```

Comment: I fixed the redundancy. I am trying to hide the actionbar when the smartphone is rotated, because of this it wont work in `onCreate`. An If I add `if(getActionBar() != null)` it doesn't enter to `getActionBar().hide()`

Comment: you know, when the phone is rotated, the activity is recreate and therefore, onCreate is called! Have you tried it?

Comment: I didn't know that. I replaced `getActionBar()` for `getSupportActionBar()` in `onConfigurationChanged` and it's working